# How to pass XML request in RestAssured test case

Tags: java, xml, xpath, rest-assured

For my rest service(create student), I have to pass a XML request(request type is application/xml) like the following one:

```
<student>
 <name>abc</name>
 </age>
 <addresses>
  <add1>
     <add_line1>pqr</add_line>
     <city>sdf</city>
  </add1>
  <add2>
    <add_line1>pqr</add_line>
    <city>sdf</city>
  </add2>
 <addresses>
</student>
```

How can we pass the whole xml to the test case?

```
@Test
public final void testCreateStudent() {
string xmlstring=//whole xml in double quote
          expect()
             .statusCode(200)
                     .body(hasXPath("/Response/status[text()='true']")
                 .with()
                     .body(xmlstring)
         .when()
                     .post("/service/student/create");
}
```

I am new in this field. can any one suggest me how to do it efficiently? Is the Xpath is correct for getting status?, if my response is like:

```
<response>
  <id>123</id>
  <status>true</status>
<response>
```

Comment: it is not clear from where come the `xmlstring` and your restassured does only expectation but not returns any xml. Because the xmlstring is in the return of your test and in the body in the same time it means you reassign it (but it does not work like it is written)

Comment: Your xml is not valid: </age> but i don't see the <age> element...